# Numerical computation of a loan and numerous parameters

Tags: numerics, finance

I'm not an expert of Wolfram Language, but I'd like to create a simple way to solve a financial problem maybe not very straightforward as it involves numerical computation, numerous variables and a procedure that I'd like to be direct for the user.

My goal is to compute a loan given some quantities that are taken back to time zero (today) that are equal to some given value. These quantities are obtained from a multiplication of the residual debt of the loan in the various epochs by two given fixed parameters.
An example could be the following:

Given $x$ as the loan, I know that the two fixed parameters are $.6$ and $.063$, the discount rate is $.0511$ and the duration of the loan is $5$ years. These quantites that must be discounted must be equal to $100.000$. How can I obtain the loan value?

I tried these code, but I'm not an expert and the problem seems not easy from a code point of view.

```
NSolve[.6*.0511Sum[((z-y)/(1+0.0511)^t),{t,0,10}]==100000,y==a-b,a==Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r, 10], EffectiveInterest[.0511, 12/12],
0] == 100000, r],b==Table[Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r, 10], EffectiveInterest[.0511, 12/12],
0] == 100000, r]*(1-(1.0511)^(-10-i))/0.0511,{i,0,10}],{z},$MinPrecision=2,$MaxPrecision=1000]
```

MinPrecision and MaxPrecision were put into the code but I don't know how to deal with them because I didn't get the meaning of the error message in the output

```
NSolve::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 1000) beyond position 5 in NSolve[0.266149 (-y+z)==100000,y==a-b,a=={{r->13019.7}},b=={{{7.68065 (r->13019.7)}},{{8.25864 (r->13019.7)}},<<7>>,{{11.9777 (r->13019.7)}},<<1>>},{z},2,1000]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

Mathematically speaking the problem should be this, if I'm not wrong

$\sum_{t=0}^5 \frac{DR_{t}\cdot0.6\cdot0.0630}{(1+.0511)^t}=100.000$
where $DR_t=L-C_t$ with $L$ as "Loan".
Thank you very much

Comment: This `NSolve[{.6*.0511Sum[((z-y)/(1+0.0511)^t),{t,0,10}]==100000,y==a-b,
a==Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r, 10], EffectiveInterest[.0511, 12/12],0] == 100000, r],
b==Table[Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r, 10], EffectiveInterest[.0511, 12/12],0] == 100000, r]*(1-(1.0511)^(-10-i))/0.0511,{i,0,10}]},{z}]` gets rid of the error message. Use `{..list of equations..}` to give `NSolve` multiple equations. BUT that still doesn't give a solution and I am not yet sure why. If you can explain a little more about your sum that you give at the bottom of your post then maybe I can code it for you.

Comment: This `r=.;a=r/.Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r, 10], EffectiveInterest[.0511, 12/12],0] == 100000, r][[1]];` clears the value of `r` and calculates a new value for `r` and assigns that to `a`. This `r=.;b=Flatten[Table[(r/.Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[r,10], EffectiveInterest[.0511,12/12], 0]==100000,r])*(1-(1.0511)^(-10-i))/0.0511,{i,0,10}]]` clears the value of `r` and calculates eleven new values and assigns all eleven of those to `b` which doesn't seem right. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interests. I try to be more clear, given the articulation of the problem. The summation at the bottom has the following meaning: "I want to know the loan that generates quantities that discounted at the given rate is equal to 100000." Of course the fixed values can be different but the goal is the same. My idea was to write the problem with z as the residual debt (z is the loan and y is the sum of capital payments given by the difference between the global period payment (capital+interest) minus interests).

Comment: Maybe the interests are computed in the wrong way because I used the table command, but I don't know how wolfram interact with all the values that it obtains. Numerically speaking, interests of each period have to be subtracted from the period payment to obtain the capital share of it.

Comment: You want to find values for unknown variables so that when you add amounts for year0, year1, ... year5 then that sum=100000. That is clear. Please give an understandable name for each unknown. Please give values for each name that is known at year 0. Please give equations showing how to calculate each unknowns for year i+1 from the unknowns in year i. I do not understand what "DR.0.6-0.0630" means or how to write a line of code that does that. Perhaps you could give values for all unknowns and show how to calculate each year from the previous year and what to sum. What values do I then change

Comment: I tried to figure out  a way through which Wolfram Cloud could compute all unknown quantites independently but maybe is not so simple. This was my idea because in my problem there is a simple french mortgage (with constant payments) and formulas for each period are kinda "recursive" from the firstone.

Comment: @Bill $DR\cdot0.6\cdot0.0630$ is the expression that generates all quantites that must be discounted: $DR$ variable is related to each period and mathematically speaking  maybe I'm not able to figure out the exact equation to be solved. Coudl Wolfram Cloud try alone the loan value, do the entire computation and give me the solution without specifing all the $DR$ variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152106/discussion-between-pepus-and-bill).